# Recursively changing file extensions on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a large S3 bucket with a nested "folder" structure containing among other things .JPG and .jpg files (uppercase and lowercase extensions).

So I need do change .JPG files to lowercase extension.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to **Copy** the old objects to the new name, then **Delete** the old objects.

If it is a one-off, I would create a spreadsheet list of Keys, then write a formula that uses the `aws s3 mv` command. This performs both a Copy and a Delete:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket/folder/foo.JPG s3://bucket/folder/foo.jpg
```

Then, copy all those commands and paste them into the Command Prompt / Terminal to trigger the rename.

For a large (over 1000) number of objects, I'd suggest doing it via a Python script that does the Copy and Delete.

Comment: Thank you, @John!